# Jquery common loading image for all divs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the code bellow to reveal a div that contains a loading image for all divs but I cannot make it work.

For example I have 4 divs and inside those divs I have included the div that holds the image loading icon. Each div has a button with same class name.
Every time that I press the button the div that holds the loading image appears only in the first div.

P.S I want to keep this structure because I am grabbing some attributes from `<a href>`

My Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".mybutton").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var title = $(this).attr("title");

            var dataString = 'id='+ id;

            $('#myloader').fadeIn("fast");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getvars.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function(html) {
                    $('#myloader').fadeOut("fast");
                }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

And my html Code:

```
<!-- Div 1 -->

<div id="Master" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div id="myloader" style="width:50px; height:50px; display:none;">Wait...</div>
    <a href="" class="mybutton" id="someid" title="sometitle">Press me</a>
</div>

<!-- Div 2 -->

<div id="Master" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div id="myloader" style="width:50px; height:50px; display:none;">Wait...</div>
    <a href="" class="mybutton" id="someid" title="sometitle">Press me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using a div id and it should be unique on a HTML document, so you should replace `#myloader` with `.myloader` 
and of course `<div id="myloader"` to `<div class="myloader"`

Comment: Hello guys, i tried to make it work but without result. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeroGravity/WdsVp/18/

Comment: It looks that you did not understand that the id has to be unique on every div. You have again duplicate id.
Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/WdsVp/72/ , although it could be achieved in many other ways.

Comment: Sport billy indeed i didnt understand it. Now i got it! Thank you! Your example works like a acharm!

Answer (score 1):

You are using same id for multiple elements. There should be only one element having an id.

Try this:

```
$(".mybutton").click(function() 
{

var b = this;

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var title = $(this).attr("title");

var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$('#myloader').fadeIn("fast");

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "getvars.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)
   {
   $(b).siblings('div')[0].fadeOut("fast");
   }

   });

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `<div id="myloader"` `to <div class="myloader"` and then change JS as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mybutton").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        var $loader = $(this).parent().find('.myloader'); //Change this

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getvars.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() { //Change this
               $loader.fadeIn("fast");
            }
            success: function(html) {
               $loader.fadeOut("fast"); //Change this
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

ID should always be unique(  that is why it is called ID..:) )..so
replace `#myloader` with `.myloader` and `<div id="myloader"` to `<div class="myloader"` ..and you can use `prev()` jquery function to get the div with loading...

your codes should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".mybutton").click(function() 
  {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var title = $(this).attr("title");

    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $(this).prev().fadeIn("fast"); //chnages here

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "getvars.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,

     success: function(html)
     {
       $(this).prev().fadeOut("fast"); //and here
     }

   });

 });
});
```